# Error: Cannot modify managed object

Tags: managed-package, picklist

I have a picklist field in an object with a controlling field and it is uploaded successfully. But when I changed it's controlling field to an another value the uploading gave an error saying :-

**Error: Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00NA0000008WtqT, field=PicklistControllerEnumOrId, state=MANAGED_RELEASED: newValue='00NA000000BKOYb', oldValue='00NA0000008lGBC'**

This error is coming when I am creating a package.
Does any know why this is happening?

And what is the workaround for it?

Answer (score 7):

I recently ran into a similar issue and was given an education on the subject:

I've seen something similar to this.  The metadata API can't support the initial setup of dependent picklists.  Set up just the initial dependency between controlling and dependent field in the browser (in the destination org) then push your package again.  You should be able to update the dependencies via the ANT push, just not create them initially.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Dan. Over a year back i came up with the same issue. I crated a blank dependency first between the two fields Using Salesforce Object detail page and later i did the deployment with the detailed dependency. It worked well.